# Workbook_NewSheet Excel VBA Error MEssage

Tags: excel, vba

I have added code to my Excel ThisWorkbook in an attempt to add a worksheet_change code to each sheet that is created in my Excel workbook. I run the code and get the following error message: Compile error: Method or data member not found.

Does anyone knwo what this could be?

```
  Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sh
    
    ' Add Worksheet_Change event to new sheet
    Dim code As String
    code = "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" & vbCrLf & _
           "    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range(""A1:E19""), Target) Is Nothing) Then" & vbCrLf & _
           "        MsgBox ""Cell "" & Target.Address & "" has changed."", vbInformation, ""Test""" & vbCrLf & _
           "    End If" & vbCrLf & _
           "End Sub"
    
    With ws.CodeModule
        .InsertLines 2, code
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You know there is a Workbook level event that watches all the worksheets for changes?  Why not use that if you want this on every sheet?

Comment: @ScottCraner Please tell me what that is

Comment: `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`  It is the same as the `Worksheet_Change` event but you need to use `sh` as the parent in your code to make sure your are referencing the correct range objects.

Comment: Excellent - how do i get this to only run after all the sheets are generated? It works but it's looping through all my code first. Is there a way to only trigger it at the end? Like a call?

Comment: Disable the change event (`Application.EnableEvents = False`), create all the worksheets, then enable it again (`Application.EnableEvents = True`)?

Comment: ^^^ Make sure you have some error handling to ensure the events are turned back on before exiting.

Comment: `With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.CodeName).CodeModule` and you'd need a reference to the VB Extensibility library.  Scott's approach is better though.

Comment: @TimWilliams No need for the reference to the library though, it works as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with a small fix:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sh
    
    ' Add Worksheet_Change event to new sheet
    Dim code As String
    code = "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" & vbCrLf & _
           "    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range(""A1:E19""), Target) Is Nothing) Then" & vbCrLf & _
           "        MsgBox ""Cell "" & Target.Address & "" has changed."", vbInformation, ""Test""" & vbCrLf & _
           "    End If" & vbCrLf & _
           "End Sub"
    
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Sh.CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines 2, code
    End With
End Sub
```